# IS NULL configuration assistance please

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm sorry this is probably very basic but i've went to a new company that uses crystal reporting, which my old company did not.

In payroll we have many deduction codes (PAYROLCD) on the pay stubs.  We recently had to add a code to all employees in one state only.

I need to figure out how to tell my query to check all pay stubs in a certain state (not a problem) for a certain date (not an issue) to find pay stubs that are missing that specific code only.  The code name is FAMLI.  I know how to write isnull({upr30300.PAYROLCD}) but i'm struggling where do i add i only want it to be for code FAMLI?

example of what i currently have
{UPR00100.EMPLCLAS} startswith ["", "CO"] and
{UPR30300.CHEKDATE} in Date (2024,1,18) to Date (2024,1,31
) and
ISNULL({UPR30300.PAYROLCD})

using this will obviously give a list of all deductions not on each paystub.  i want FAMLI missing only

Answer (score 0):

Change

`and ISNULL({UPR30300.PAYROLCD})`

to

`and instr({UPR30300.PAYROLCD}, "FAMLI") = 0`